# how to sort a flex datagrid according to multiple columns?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid

I have a datagrid, populated as shown below.  When the user clicks on a column header, I would like to sort the rows using a lexicographic sort in which the selected column is used first, then the remaining columns are used in left-to-right order to break any ties.  How can I code this?

(I have one answer, which I'll post below, but it has a problem -- I'll be thrilled if somebody can provide a better one!)

Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    layout="absolute" creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">

    <mx:Script source="GridCode.as" />

    <mx:DataGrid id="theGrid" x="61" y="55" width="466" height="317">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="A"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="B"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="C"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>

</mx:Application>
```

And here's the backing code:

```
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.collections.Sort;
import mx.collections.SortField;
import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
import mx.events.DataGridEvent;

public function onCreationComplete():void
{
    var ar:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    var ob:Object;
    for( var i:int=0; i<20; i++ )
    {
        ob = new Object();
        ob["A"] = i;
        ob["B"] = i%3;
        ob["C"] = i%5;
        ar.addItem(ob);
    }
    this.theGrid.dataProvider = ar;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best answer I've found so far is to capture the headerRelease event when the user clicks:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="theGrid" x="61" y="55" width="466" height="317"
        headerRelease="onHeaderRelease(event)">
```

The event handler can then apply a sort order to the data:

```
private var lastIndex:int = -1;
private var desc:Boolean = false;

public function onHeaderRelease(evt:DataGridEvent):void
{
    evt.preventDefault();

    var srt:Sort = new Sort();
    var fields:Array = new Array();

    if( evt.columnIndex == lastIndex )
    {
        desc = !desc;
    }
    else
    {
        desc = false;
        lastIndex = evt.columnIndex;
    }

    fields.push( new SortField( evt.dataField, false, desc ) );
    if( evt.dataField != "A" )
        fields.push( new SortField("A", false, desc) );
    if( evt.dataField != "B" )
        fields.push( new SortField("B", false, desc) );
    if( evt.dataField != "C" )
        fields.push( new SortField("C", false, desc) );
    srt.fields = fields;

    var ar:ArrayCollection = this.theGrid.dataProvider as ArrayCollection;
    ar.sort = srt;
    ar.refresh();
}
```

However this approach has a well-known problem, which is that the column headers no longer display little arrows to show the sort direction.  This is a side-effect of calling 
    evt.preventDefault()
however you must make that call or else your custom sort won't be applied.